# What do Agag, April Fools, and Mt. Sinai have to do with each other?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

It's a known rule in Gematrias, that any words with the same Gematria (or off by one) have a connection.

Now the Gematria of אֲגַג מֶלֶךְ עֲמָלֵק is 337, the Gematria of אחד באפריל is 336, and Har Sinai is 335, which shows on an inner connection.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: So April Fool's is the center, and the other two surround it "off by one"? I'll have to see what I can find... Great question, and welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please consider [registering](//judaism.stackexchange.com/users/signup-unregistered) your account, to [enable](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) more site features, including voting.

Comment: welcome yo Mi yodeya leitz! Thanks for sharing the question. consider registering your account to fully utilise the site's features.

Comment: April Fools day was setup when the Gregory moved New years from April (the month of their *holiday* to January to attract the pagans to join him.  He called those wo objected *fools*. You might do something with that.

Comment: Actually off by any odd number (and certain even numbers) means there is a connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

April fool origin theories include miscalculating or disagreement about dates of the new year.

This is very connected to Har Sinai and the miscalculation of 40 days which led to the eigel.

This is also connected to Aggag in so far as Shaul HaMelech miscalculated and said 'I should really leave one Amaleiki'.

(Little known fact is this is actually the source that a  gemataria can be one off.)

Another famous miscalculation that belongs on this list is האפרים. This also equals 336. The tribe of Ephraim famously miscalculated the time of geulas mitzraim and left early, only to meet their fate at the hands of the Plishtim. The happy ending was when they were revived from the dead in Yechezkel's vision. That's why its האפרים, Ha! Ephraim.